# Insertion of values in database

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-adapters

Hey I am using IBM Worklight V6.2.I want to insert values into database

My Html Code is

```
 <h1>Please Enter The Car Details</h1>
 <form >    
Car No:<input type="number"  id="carnum" placeholder="Please enter your no" ><br><br>
Details:<input type="text" id= "details" placeholder="Please enter car details" > <br><br>
<input type="submit" value="Register" onclick="loadFeeds1()">

</form>
```

My procedure is:

```
var  users = WL.Server.createSQLStatement("insert into car(carno,details) values (?,?)");
 function getusers(carno,details) {
return WL.Server.invokeSQLStatement({
    preparedStatement : users,
    parameters : [carno,details]
 });
 }
```

My js file is this

```
 function loadFeeds1(){
 var invocationData = {
           adapter:"car2",
              procedure:"getuser",
              parameters:["carno","details"]
         };


 WL.Server.invokeProcedure(invocationData,{
     onSuccess :loadFeedsSuccess1,
    onFailure :loadFeedsFailure1,
 });
}

function loadFeedsSuccess1() {

WL.Logger.debug("inserted");


 }

function loadFeedsFailure1() {
WL.Logger.debug("failed");

}
```

I am able to invoke procedure from adapter..but not able to see when i insert values in browser.not it is showing anything in console..Kindly suggest...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't simply place the `ID`s of your `input`s as the `WL.client.invokeProcedure`'s parameters... You need to pass their value.

For example:

```
function loadFeeds1(){
    var invocationData = {
        adapter:"car2",
        procedure:"getuser",
        parameters:[$('#carnum').val(),$('#details').val()]
    };

    WL.Server.invokeProcedure(invocationData,{
        onSuccess :loadFeedsSuccess1,
        onFailure :loadFeedsFailure1,
    });
}
```

---

This is an end-to-end scenario, where I take 2 values from the HTML and insert them into the database. To re-create, you can you use the WorklightTraining.sql scheme provided in the [Adapters sample project](http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/docs/v620/WorklightAdaptersProject.zip). You can see it works because after the 'success', if you will refresh the database - you'll see the new record.

**HTML:**

```
<h1>Test Insert Into Database</h1>
<input type="text" id="value1" placeholder="value1"/><br/>
<input type="text" id="value2" placeholder="value2"/><br/>
<input type="button" value="Insert values to database" onclick="insertValuesToDB();"/>
```

**main.js:**

```
function insertValuesToDB() {
    var invocationData = {
        adapter: 'insertValuesAdapter',
        procedure: 'insertValuesProcedure',
        parameters: [$('#value1').val(), $('#value2').val()]
    };

    WL.Client.invokeProcedure(invocationData, {onSuccess: insertSuccess, onFailure: insertFailure});
}

function insertSuccess() {
    alert("success");
}

function insertFailure() {
    alert("failure");
}
```

**Adapter XML:**

```
...
...
<connectivity>
    <connectionPolicy xsi:type="sql:SQLConnectionPolicy">
        <dataSourceDefinition>
            <driverClass>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</driverClass>
            <url>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/worklight_training</url>
            <user>Worklight</user>
            <password>Worklight</password> 
        </dataSourceDefinition> 
    </connectionPolicy>
    <loadConstraints maxConcurrentConnectionsPerNode="5" />
</connectivity>

<procedure name="insertValuesProcedure"/>
...
...
```

**Adapter implementation:**

```
var insertValuesProcedureStatement = WL.Server.createSQLStatement("INSERT INTO users(userId, firstName, lastName, password) VALUES (?,?, 'someLastName', 'somePassword')");

function insertValuesProcedure(value1,value2) {
    return WL.Server.invokeSQLStatement({
        preparedStatement : insertValuesProcedureStatement,
        parameters : [value1,value2]
    });
}
```

Comment: Idan I tried this thing too myself but it is still neither working nor the console is showing any error

Comment: I don't know your database setup, but I used the worklight_training database scheme provided in the Adapters sample project and it is working fine for me. I will update my answer accordingly.

Comment: I am using simple Sql database with database car,table car and field are carno and details

Comment: "simple" doesn't help; anyway, I updated my answer. This works 100%.