# how to insert data in database using MobileFirst adapters ?

Tags: mysql, ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-adapters

I want to add lines in my database. I have created an SQL adapter and a procedure to add data butt it doesn't work (no changes in my database)

Comment: You have to post your code: Read the stackoverflow how to pages.

Comment: Many of the code samples you will come across have little or no error handling and hence you may get a failure to insert (for example because you violate a database constraint) and not report the reason. My first recommendation is to check that your code error paths do report the errors somewhere. For example: stop the database, run your test. This must fail. Ensure that you see some useful error message somewhere. Now restart the database and see what errors you get when you try to insert.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one end-to-end example of adding data from the HTML and into a database, using MobileFirst Adapters: [Insertion of values in database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25163785/insertion-of-values-in-database)

You need to provide your code and you need to provide the error you're getting.