# retrieve data from a form and insert it in a database using adapters in worklight?

Tags: database, forms, ibm-mobilefirst, adapter

i have an inscription form , and i don't know how to retrieve data from this form and send it to the database using adapter in worklight
i think that i should use jquery . val() to retrieve data and use it in a procedure to put it in the database , please some help :/
thanks !!

var procedure1Statement = WL.Server.createSQLStatement("select COLUMN1, COLUMN2 from TABLE1 where COLUMN3 = ?");
function procedure1(param) {
    return WL.Server.invokeSQLStatement({
        preparedStatement : procedure1Statement,
        parameters : [param]
    });
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question has been answered multiple times by now so I will classify this as a duplicate.

Please see this question: [Insertion of values in database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25163785/insertion-of-values-in-database)

And look at all the other information about this, here: https://www.google.co.il/search?q=worklight+adapter+add+to+database&oq=worklight+adapter+add+to+database&aqs=chrome..69i57.7638j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8