# how to save current location in db2 database ? and then access it on google maps

Tags: javascript, android, db2, ibm-mobilefirst

How to save Google maps locaation into db2 ? using javascript . I am currently working on a code where we can  save current location  latitude and longitude automatically. I use Google maps API, but I don't know how to save latitude and longitude in my database and then access it. Please help in saving users location in database  Thanx very much

code current location

db2

database name 
parkgo

select from park  (lon,lat);

Comment: read first how to ask good question. the question is poorly structured

Comment: Check out DB2 Spatial Extender to store spatial data http://www-03.ibm.com/software/products/en/db2spaext  or 
http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/tutorials/dm-1202db2spatialdata1/

Comment: i know how to connect with database  ,but  i dont know how to save maps lat nn lon in database

Answer (score 0):

Typically called "search", you use it to find similar-asked questions that will provide you with examples and guide how to do the same with your own problem. For example: [Insertion of values in database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25163785/insertion-of-values-in-database)

The fact that you're using some "lat long values" doesn't matter. A string is a string is a value. You take it and you put it in your database by invoking an adapter the calls an SQL query. See the link above.